# Error 1073741819 when launching AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, qemu

I've been playing around with settings of OpenGL renderer in AVD.

[image]

Once I finished, closed the editor and tried to launch the virtual device, the following error with code `1073741819` was thrown.

```
ERROR: Invalid GPU mode 'angle9', use one of: host swiftshader_indirect. If you're already using one of those modes, the emulator installation may be corrupt. Please re-install the emulator.
```

However, there is no possibility switching the settings back. Manualy editing config files of the virtual device wont help anyway. Neither reinstalling or deleting Android Studio at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only solution came from following steps:

#### 1. Locate the emulator location

Hit the SDK tools icon in order to get the exact location

[image]

#### 2. Launch emulator manually

```
> cd C:\Users\jakub.meinlschmidt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
> emulator -list-avds
Nexus_S_API_29
> emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_29 -gpu host
```

If your virtual device is not appearing the list, try to reboot your computer (worked for me).

#### 3. Open AVD Editor

Once you successfully launch your virtual device, navigate to the OpenGL settings (as shown in the first picture) and switch to a different option.